# DataTable Rows property

Tags: c#, vb.net

VB allows direct indexing on the System.Data.DataTable type instead of calling the 'Rows' property.  'Rows' is not an indexer, but a regular property returning a DataRowCollection.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim x = dt(0) 'instead of Dim x = dt.Rows(0)
```

C# requires that the 'Rows' property be called explicitly:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var x = dt.Rows(0);
```

Why is this?  And is there a way to find this behavior using reflection?  The reflection method GetDefaultMembers does not return anything for System.Data.DataTable.

Comment: In C#, you cannot directly apply an indexer to an `IEnumerable` collection (`IEnumerable<string> l = new List<string>(); var s = l[0]; <=` can't do, `IList<string> l = new List<string>(); var s = l[0]; <=` can do). You can do both in  VB.Net.

Comment: [EnumerableRowCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.enumerablerowcollection) is the result of a LINQ query. It only implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Jimi: Sorry - I had removed the reference from another project in my test solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the References for your VB project, you'll see that there is one for System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll.  Remove that and you'll see that your code no longer works in VB.  It appears that the VB compiler has been written to somehow map this:

```vb
Dim x = dt(0)
```

to this:

```vb
Dim x = dt.AsEnumerable().ElementAt(0)
```

where the C# compiler does not do the equivalent and you have to call those methods explicitly. It's not unusual for the VB compiler to do these little helpful things that hide some of the complexity.  Personally, I always use the `Rows` property anyway. It's not like it's onerous to do so.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas, see [How LINQ to Dataset works in VB](https://web.archive.org/web/20190315012020/https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/how-linq-to-dataset-works-in-vb-jonathan-aneja/)

Comment: @TnTinMn: Yes, but what I was most interested in was why VB allows the shortcut and how I could determine that via reflection (which it appears you can't).

Comment: @DaveDoknjas, you could do as the VB compiler apparently does and look for appropriate extension methods that are in scope but that would be rather painful. It's worth noting that the VB compiler does something similar in mapping indexing to `ElementAt` that the C# compiler doesn't. Even without a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll, VB still supports `Dim row = table.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)()(0)`, even though you can't actually index an `IEnumerable(Of T)`. C#, on the other hand, does not support `var row = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()[0];`.

Comment: I'm ready to give up on how VB does this - even after removing the System.Data.DataSetExtensions reference, the VB code still works, so I don't think any extension methods are a factor here.  I think that the VB compiler just allows treating 'Rows' as an indexer - no real logic there except for VB compiler idiosyncrasy.

Comment: I created a new VB WinForms app project, created a `Load` event handler for the form and copied the first code snippet from your question into it and there was no issue. I then expanded the References node in the Solution Explorer, selected the System.Data.DataSetExtensions node and pressed Delete. The code was then flagged as bad with the error message *"Class 'DataTable' cannot be indexed because it has no default property"*. Even with `Option Strict Off` it did the same. I think you did something wrong. It appears to work exactly as explained.

Comment: Either you're doing something wrong or your IDE is broken. I just tried the same thing with a Console app and removed all references other than System.dll and System.Data.dll and then pasted your first code snippet into the `Main` method and got the same error message. For the purpose of this question, it's probably academic anyway but if you or your IDE is broken then you ought to fix it to avoid other things going wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Sincere apologies - in my solution I was removing the assembly reference from the wrong project.  Your answer is spot on.

Comment: FWIW, your example of `Dim row = table.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)()(0)` is attaching a call to `ElementAtOrDefault` to achieve that that trick.  That is covered in the language specification under [Default Query Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/expressions#default-query-indexer).